# Son playing on IPad instead of doing homework

Tags: ios, ipad

My son is playing with his IPad instead of doing his homework on it.  Is there an app to see what apps he is using along with how long he is on each app?

Comment: I assume you do not use the parental controls ? So how long after it has been used you want that information to be available?

Comment: This is his school issued IPad but I can add an app.  Within 24 to 48 hours.

Comment: Consider using [parenting.stackexchange.com](parenting.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: Stop trying to solve a non-technical problem with a technical solution.

Answer (score 9):

Without installing additional applications (since is not your iPad after all), you could use the Battery consumption indicator that comes with iOS as a rough indicator how long a app was running- consuming battery. It does not tell you the time of usage but the amount.

The benefit is you will not be intrusive nor raise any suspicion from the "user" looking at the battery consumption, as compared to some tracking software, since the kids are very clever these days.

[iOS 8 tells you what app is draining your iPhone's battery](http://appleinsider.com/articles/14/09/26/ios-8-tells-you-what-app-is-draining-your-iphones-battery)

Example for 7 days (Clash of Clans is a game) and here you can see the heavy usage over a week that might help you managing the situation.

[image: CoC]

Comment: You could also jailbreak and there's a tweak on Cydia that improves and gives more features to the battery usage statistics.

Comment: Keep in mind that games will probably use disproportionately more battery than, say, reading a textbook. So 50% battery on a game and 5% battery on Safari doesn't mean that the user has been playing the game for ten times as long.

Comment: @arxanas The op can take advantage of that.  "Son, look! You have been playing games instead of doing homework! 90% of the time is spent gaming!" That way, he spends think, "wow, I had no idea I was playing that long" and possibly adjusts the time he spends on games. A little deceptive, but isn't that a part of parenting?

Comment: @user0000001 Given that this is a [school-issued iPad](#comment184301_156732), I don't think jailbreaking is an option.

Comment: @erdekhayser *"A little deceptive, but isn't that a part of parenting?"* I hope not.  Certainly not a part of good parenting.

Comment: @AdamDavis Good thing I'm not a parent then! I was basing that comment on what my parents used to do, trying to trick me into a better behavior. It worked, sometimes.

Comment: @AdamDavis But that is a question better asked on parenting.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is a clever suggestion, but I agree with arxanas, DONT'T actually do this. If there is one thing that kids resent most, it's unfair treatment. And take it from me, if you try to show them false data and punish them based on that data, they will feel cheated and unfairly treated. @hjbeetnik

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned that it's a school-issued iPad. Many school districts use mobile device management packages, such as maas360 or Lightspeed to control these devices.

You may want to contact the school to see if they have any recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its better to configure your router. You can control the access over it or you can give his iPad just access to some pages, which he will need for his homework. And after the homework is done, you can remove the access control. Is a little more work than installing an app, but it does really helps.

Comment: Could you tell some ways to configure the router ?

Comment: This depends on the router but at most routers in the configuration setting you can give give fixed Ip-Addresses to a MAC-Address (the iPad) and set up a filter. You can block urls and access to IP-addresses (like the servers the apps will need to get information from). And you can set a period of time when this filter is activated.

Just take a look at the advanced settings of your router

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apple kit, use Airport Utility to prevent internet access during certain hours. Not the complete answer to your problem I’m afraid, but it stops my teenage sons browsing/chatting etc. when they should be sleeping !

Using Spotlight, open Airport Utility. It will show you a diagrammatic representation of your Airport Extreme, Express and other devices. Double click on your Airport Extreme (or the nearest booster if you have them and want to do it on a local basis) and click ‘Edit’ in the bottom right hand corner. From the options that pop up, chose ’Network’ then check the box labelled ‘Enable Access Control’. Select 'Timed Access Control'. You can now entire the days and times you want the router to function. Don’t forget to save ! –

Comment: How do you do this?

Comment: Open Airport Utility. It will show you a diagrammatic representation of your Airport Express and other devices.

Comment: Using Spotlight, open Airport Utility. It will show you a diagrammatic representation of your Airport Extreme, Express and other devices. Double click on your Airport Extreme (or the nearest booster if you have them and want to do it on a local basis) and click ‘Edit’ in the bottom right hand corner. From the options that pop up, chose ’Network’ then check the box labelled ‘Enable Access Control’. Select 'Timed Access Control'. You can now entire the days and times you want the router to function. Don’t forget to save !

Comment: Put that as an edit to your answer